# Projection of Fréchet mean(s) to tangent space of a Riemannian manifold versus mean of the projection of these points

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $\{x_1\dots x_n\}\subset (M,g),$ where $(M,g)$ is a complete finite $d$ dimensional a Riemannian manifold. Let us denote by $\bar{x}$ a Fréchet mean of  $\{x_1\dots x_n\},$ i.e. a minimizer of the function:

$$f:(M,g)\to \mathbb{R}:= f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}d_g(x,x_i)^2.$$

where $d_g$ is the metric on $M$ induced by the Riemannian metric $g.$

Denote by $log_{\bar{x}}(.): U\subset M \to T_{\bar{x}}(M)$ the inverse of the exponential map at $\bar{x},$ when the latter is invertible (i.e. inside the cut locus or in the segment domain). Assume that $\{x_1\dots x_n\}$ is inside the cut locus of $\bar{x}.$  Below we use the phrase 'projection of $p\in M$' to denote $log_{\bar{x}}(p) \in T_{\bar{x}}(M).$

Consider two points on $T_{\bar{x}}(M):$

(1) the average/mean of the projection: $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}log_{\bar{x}}(x_i)$ and

(2) the projection of the Fréchet mean: $0 \in T_{\bar{x}}(M).$

Clearly (1) and (2) may not be identical points. In some cases they can be, e.g. is we pick just two points on $S^1$, they're identical. One can come up with examples with more than two points as well.

**My questions are:**

1. Are there theorems/literature on this topic that guarantees that (1) and (2) are identical points, or out somewhat generally when is projection of the Fréchet mean equals the mean (in the tangent space) of the projections?
2. At least in particular cases, are there any kind of known bounds between (1) and (2) above using the maximum (or minimum) sectional curvature of $(M,g)?$

P.S. If needed, you can assume that the Fréchet mean is unique. (I think!) it's known when the manifold has non-positive curvature.